SQL Server: What benefit does a non-unique index have versus a unique index containing the primary key as the last index column?
We have an application server (written by us) which consumes a "model" and provides most of of the database commissioning work (creating tables, indexes, etc). When constructing indexes, it does not currently support "non-unique" indexes and instead creates everything as a unique index (ie. it uses the CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement). When we define indexes in our "model", if we need a non-unique index we add the primary key field to the end of our index definition to achieve the "equivalent" outcome of a "non-unique" index. I say "equivalent" loosely - in the sense that duplicate values from different table rows won't error as a duplicate key violation.
A long-standing goal has been to get the application server to permit non-unique indexes, but it's always been a low priority since the "equivalent" behaviour described above makes it seem "unnecessary".
So, my question is whether there are other less obvious reasons why a non-unique index can be "better" than a unique index which concatenates the primary key. It would seem intuitive that a reduction in storage space is one benefit, but even that may not be as clear-cut as I think.
For example, could there be benefits in query optimisation, increased performance when updating the index, and so forth?
We are targeting SQL Server 2016 and higher.

For nonclustered indexes that aren't declared as unique SQL Server will implicitly add any missing clustered index key columns to the end of the key anyway to make them unique. So in the case that your PK is the clustered index your practice just makes explicit what happens anyway

SQL Server will add the clustered key in any non-clustered index, so you're doubling up.  It might optimise that away - not sure.
In any case, non unique indexes are helpful for other reasons, e.g. making foreign keys practical and speeding up queries.
I'm guessing you're getting away with it because of low data volume or over-provisioned servers.  Generally, if you index appropriately and correctly to your data model and queries you'll make the most of your hardware and disk space.  There's a reason every single database allows unique and non-unique indexes!
As an aside, I am wondering what value this adds and why creating models is common enough that you have a layer to do it.  Typically the database schema and indexes are quite static between releases or significant data updates.

The clustered index keys are only added to non-unique non-clustered indexes.
